# Bad value for type timestamp on production server

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, jboss, timestamp, seam

I'm working with: seam 2.2.2 + hibernate + richfaces + jboss 5.1 + postgreSQL

I have an module which needs to load some data from the database. Easy. The problem is, on development it works fine, 100%, but when I deploy on my production server and try to get the data, an error rise:

```
could not read column value from result set: fechahor9_504_; Bad value for type timestamp : [C@122e5cf
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22007
Bad value for type timestamp : [C@122e5cf
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
```

[more errors]

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type timestamp : [C@122e5cf
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.TimestampUtils.loadCalendar(TimestampUtils.java:232)
```

[more errors]

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Trailing junk on timestamp: ''
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.TimestampUtils.loadCalendar(TimestampUtils.java:226)
```

I can't understand why it works on my machine (development) and why not on production. Any clues? Anyone gone through the same problem? Is exactly the same compilation

Comment: chances are that you don't have the same version of the jdbc driver in production and in your machine.

Comment: What versions of PostgreSQL are you using in development and production? Does your application validate the timestamps before attempting to insert them? Where does 'C@122e5cf' come from? That appears to the bad value thats attempted to be inserted into the timestamp field.

Comment: I'm using the same jdbc driver on dev and production. PostgreSQL version is 8.4, running on an ubuntu server, both prod and dev. I tried pointing my dev app to the production DB and it works like a charm. Only if I run the application from the jBoss on production server, the error arises. The 'C@122e5cf' I believe is the entity I´m trying to recover with the query. That entity has some Date values (timestamp annotation)... I have some other entities with that kind of columns and they don't give errors on production

Comment: Stefano Travelli was right. I was checking the jBoss on production and there was an old jdbc driver on [jboss_dir]/common/lib from an old jwebstart application (not developed by me). Deleted that jdbc and it works fine. I should check if the old application is still needed and if so, check if it still works without the jdbc being there or with an upgraded version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stefano Travelli was right. I was checking the jBoss on production and there was an old jdbc driver on [jboss_dir]/common/lib from an old jwebstart application (not developed by me). Deleted that jdbc and it works fine. I should check if the old application is still needed and if so, check if it still works without the jdbc being there or with an upgraded version.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the driver story is ..
but the problem for me show up when JDBC tries to parse  **bigint** from the DB to

```
myOjbect.setDate(Date date){...}
```

the other "JDBC friendly" is ignorred for some reason .

```
myOjbect.setDate(long date){...}
```

So .. removing the **Date** setter and leaving a **long** one resolves the problem.
This is a Big workaround .. but may help someone out there :)