# PSQLException on heroku

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, apache-cayenne

I use java, apache-cayenne and postgreSQL.

My app works fine on desktop, but I get an error when I run it on Heroku:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type timestamp/date/time: 
{1}
```

there are also warnings:

```
INFO org.apache.cayenne.log.JdbcEventLogger - --- transaction started.
WARN org.apache.cayenne.access.types.SerializableTypeFactory - Haven't found suitable ExtendedType for class 'java.time.LocalDate'. Most likely you need to define a custom ExtendedType.
WARN org.apache.cayenne.access.types.SerializableTypeFactory - SerializableType will be used for type conversion.
INFO org.apache.cayenne.log.JdbcEventLogger - --- transaction started.
INFO org.apache.cayenne.log.JdbcEventLogger - SELECT t0.DATE, t0.ROOM, t0.TIME, t0.TYPE, t0.PROFESSOR_ID, t0.SUBJECT_ID, t0.LESSON_ID FROM Lesson t0 JOIN Subject t1 ON (t0.SUBJECT_ID = t1.SUBJECT_ID) WHERE (t0.DATE = ?) AND (t1.USER_ID = ?) [bind: 1->DATE:2017-12-08, 2->USER_ID:81627965]
```

Here is my xml:

```
<db-entity name="Lesson">
    <db-attribute name="DATE" type="DATE"/>
    <db-attribute name="LESSON_ID" type="INTEGER" isPrimaryKey="true" isMandatory="true"/>
    <db-attribute name="PROFESSOR_ID" type="INTEGER"/>
    <db-attribute name="ROOM" type="VARCHAR" length="50"/>
    <db-attribute name="SUBJECT_ID" type="INTEGER"/>
    <db-attribute name="TIME" type="TIME"/>
    <db-attribute name="TYPE" type="INTEGER"/>
</db-entity>
<obj-entity name="Lesson" className="com.intetics.organizerbot.entities.Lesson" dbEntityName="Lesson">
    <obj-attribute name="date" type="java.time.LocalDate" db-attribute-path="DATE"/>
    <obj-attribute name="room" type="java.lang.String" db-attribute-path="ROOM"/>
    <obj-attribute name="time" type="java.time.LocalTime" db-attribute-path="TIME"/>
    <obj-attribute name="type" type="int" db-attribute-path="TYPE"/>
</obj-entity>
```

I work with the same Heroku Postgres database from desktop and Heroku.

It seems there is some problem connected with LocalDate class. But I have no idea why everything works fine on my computer, while there are problems on heroku.

I also tried to deploy jar which worked fine and it still doesn't work.

Do you have any idea on why this happens and how can I fix it?

Simular question wath asked about production server [Bad value for type timestamp on production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857539/bad-value-for-type-timestamp-on-production-server)
but I doesn't seem I can apply it's answers on Heroku.

Comment: I'd bet it's a driver version issue too.

Comment: what are the dependencies and versions you use for apache-cayenne?

Comment: I use cayenne-server and cayenne-java8. Both versions 4.0.M5

Comment: It seems like you might have more than one version of cayenne or the jdbc driver on your path.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Java 8 `java.time.*` classes from Cayenne you need to make sure you include **cayenne-java8** module to your project, see this [docs](http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/4.0/cayenne-guide/ext-java8.html) for details. Without it Cayenne just don't know how to handle those classes.